# Git: master branch merged into master? (with graph picture)

Tags: git, git-merge, git-branch, git-commit

I don't understand the following GitLab graph and I'm lacking vocabulary to express my question precisely. For reference, the graph below shows:

- [linux-kernel stable repository](https://gitlab.com/linux-kernel/stable/-/network/master) mirror on GitLab
- Highest (most recent) commit: [7a31ec4d](https://gitlab.com/linux-kernel/stable/-/commit/7a31ec4d215a800b504de74b248795f8be666f8e)
- Lowest (oldest) commit: [a68de80f](https://gitlab.com/linux-kernel/stable/-/commit/a68de80f61f6af397bc06fb391ff2e571c9c4d80)

<sup>I am not contributing to linux-kernel. Curiosity just drove me there and this GitLab graph confused me.</sup>

[image: GitLab graph]

(Ignore green branches)

Please, correct any wrong vocabulary in the following questions.

- Between arrow **1** and arrow **2**, the left side `master` branch has no commit, while the right one has some.
- The arrow **1** shows a point where `master` is like "diverging" from `master` itself. But there is no commit between the moment it "diverges" and the moment it is merged. Then it is not really a branch? How is this called? Why one would do this, and how?
- At arrow **2**, the "diverged" `master` is merged back into `master`. What is the point of doing so? How is it called? A use case would help to understand.
- Why is there a "hole" between the commit pointed by arrow **1** and the next commit on the right side `master`? How does this work?

I feel like all these points are connected by a git logic, but I can't figure out which one and my lack of vocabulary didn't help to find relevant search results.

Comment: Git can have multiple roots ("intial" commits) so that's what you are seeing there.

Answer (score 1):

It happens every time you want to merge a branch (say, a feature) into another branch that hasn!t moved (with `git merge --no-ff`). If you allow gir to merge at will in that scenario, if does a fast-forward so there is no merge.... but if you want to make sure that the feature branch stays *on the side* and a new merge revision is created regardless, you use `--no-ff` and you are done. This is useful in cases when you want to be able to move features around. A simple example: backports. If you didn!t merge like this in this scenario, you would have a hard time knowing where the feature starts and where it ends.